# Select precise data's value in JSON object using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, web

Currently new & working on a web app using AngularJS, using Nginx serv.

I want to select some precise values to put them in a html table.

I kept searching and never find an adequate solution.

Do you have an idea on how can I make this work?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $http.get('variables.json').success(function(data) {
                 $scope.variables = data;
          });
        });
        </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/css/style.css">
  </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="variables">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="var in variables">
          {{var.b}}
          {{var.a}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON File:

```
 {
  "a":6084.0,
  "b":979
 }
```

I just put an example of the JSON file. My purpose is to display for example just the b or a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read as (key,value) in $variables and display value.

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in variables">
      {{key}}:{{value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Demo link
https://plnkr.co/edit/nTUOvyMHcDRdtSzyecLw?p=preview

Comment: Thx, but here it displays all the values right? If I just want to display the value of b (979)? For example in Java I would parse the JSON file, get the value of b and put it in a variable so i can use it later. Here I would like to separate the values so I can build a html table and organize it as I wish. I dunno if it is achievable with Angular...

Comment: If you just need "b" value from variables, you can directly access using {{variables.b}}. Otherwise, you have to change your JSON format.

Comment: I've seen that before but when I do this I actually have no response, no console error but no display in my table.
<td style="font-weight:bold;" ng-model="var">{{var.b}}</td> if the syntax was wrong the console would yell at me right?

Comment: try using {{variables.b}} not {{var.b}}. please check the updated plunker link

Comment: Oh yeah got it thx! I also needed to delete the ng-repeat and it finally works super fine :) Thank you for your time!
I'm using it like this : <td>{{variables.DifferentClient | number:2}}</td>

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat only works if the data in your json will be Array Since the data is the Object it will not find any element so it won't showing values .

change the Json as below:

```
[{
  "a":6084.0,
  "b":979
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The directive [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) works with objects if the following syntax is used:

`<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>`